# Composition of continuous functions is continuous - problem in understanding the proof because of the domains

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-explanation

I study calculus and I have recently learned the definition of function being continuous at some point. I have seen the proof that the composition of continuous functions is also continuous but I do not understand it. To make my question clear I try to show you how I would have proven it and then I discuss the points of confusion. I must note that I have no clue about topology or set theory but I like to think about sets - if I do it incorrectly or I use them in a way I should not/ cannot, please tell me and I will try to make my thoughts clearer. Help is very appreciated.

Let $g$ be a function (which is also a set but intuitively a rule) that associates some real number from real number set $\mathbb{R}$ to a number in set $G$. Let $f$ be a function that associates some real number from set $\mathbb{R}$ to a number in set $F$. Assume that $g$ is continuous at $a$ and
$g(a) = m$, and also that $f$ is continuous at $m$.

That means that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_1 > 0$ so that for all $x$ if $0 < |x-a| < \delta_1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $|g(x) - g(a)| = |g(x) - m| < \varepsilon$. Also, for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_2 > 0$ so that for all $x$ if $0 < |x-m| < \delta_2$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $|f(x) - f(m)| < \varepsilon$.

I want to consider the composite function $f \circ g$ which I understand to be a rule that associates some real number from $\mathbb{R}$ to $G$ using function $g$ and then takes element from $G$ and associates element to it from $F$ using function $f$.

**Confusion 1** : Is it true that the domain of the function $f$ in the case of the composite function is $G$ and not $\mathbb{R}$?

Because $g(x)$ are just real numbers just as $x$ are, I can write continuity of $f$ as that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_2 > 0 $ so that for all $g(x)$ if $ 0 < |g(x) - m| < \delta_2 $ and $g(x) \in G$ then $|f(g(x)) - f(m)| < \varepsilon$. Continuity of $g$ tells me that no matter what $\delta_2$ is, I can find a $\delta_1$ such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta_1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $|g(x) - m| < \delta_2$.

**Confusion 2**: I am worried that I can ensure that $|g(x) - m| < \varepsilon$ but that does not neccessarily mean that there is at least one $g(x)$ that satisfies that $g(x) \in G$ and $0 < |g(x) - m|$.

Assume that there exists $\delta_3 > 0$ such that for all $g(x)$ if $0 < |g(x) - m| < \delta_3$ then $g(x) \in G$.

Now I can take $\delta = \textrm{min}(\delta_2,\delta_3)$. Thus, for each $\varepsilon > 0$ I can find $\delta_1$ such that for all $x$ if $0 < |x-a| < \delta_1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $|g(x) - m| < \delta_2$ and by the assumptions before, considering all $g(x)$ such that $0 < |g(x) - m| < \delta$ and $g(x) \in G$ leads to the fact that $|f(g(x)) - f(m)| < \varepsilon $ as one desires.

**Confusion 3**: All of the proofs I've seen so far do not assume existence of $\delta_3$. Why? Is it really not needed?

**Confusion 4**: My proof seems to me fallacious because if I know that some function $h$ is continuous then using this theorem (assuming it is correct) I cannot prove that function $h$ is continuous by taking identity function $I$ and considering composite function $h = h \circ I$. I cannot prove it because there is no such $\delta_3$ that is used in my proof.

Comment: You can prove that "calculus" definition of continuity is equivalent to stardard one (preimage of open set is open), then observe that this property is obviously retained by composition.

Comment: For problem 1: you do need $f$ to be defined on the range of $g$ in order to make sense of $f \circ g$. As for the rest of it, the point is: let $\varepsilon_1 > 0$, take $\delta_1(\varepsilon_1)$ from the definition of continuity of $f$. Now take $\varepsilon_2=\delta_1(\varepsilon_1)$ in the definition of continuity of $g$, obtaining a $\delta_2$ which is your overall $\delta$ for $f \circ g$. There is no need for a $\delta_3$.

Comment: The idea of this procedure is: to make two values of $f \circ g$ be close together, you have to make the values of $g$ be close together to an extent which is determined by how fast $f$ changes (which is measured by how small $\delta_1$ is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worry about $G$ is not needed: all you need is that $f$ is defined in the image of $g$, which it is.

Now fix $\varepsilon>0$. As you said, there exists $\delta_2$ such that $|y-m|<\delta_2$ implies $|g(y)-g(m)|<\varepsilon$. Using this $\delta_2$ as "epsilon"
for $f$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(a)|<\delta_2$. So now, when $|x-a|<\delta$, you have $|f(g(a))-g(m)|<\varepsilon$, since $|f(x)-m|<\delta_2$.

Now, in practice, most functions are continuous on an open interval, and not just at a point. In that situation, all this can be avoided if you prove, once in your life, prove that continuity of $f$ on an interval is equivalent to $f^{-1}(V)$ open for every open set $V$. Now, if $g$ is also continuous, $$(f\circ g)^{-1}(V)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(V))$$ is open, so the composition is continuous.